# Convex hull area: what are the output units?

Tags: qgis, area, convex-hull

I have what I hope is a simple question. I'm doing convex hull calculations. What I have is `area(convex_hull($geometry))`.

I get a number and that's all well and fine. Since I need to get a ratio of that area with the original polygon, I need to know what units the convex hull area is in. Does anyone have an idea on this?

Also, am I doing something naive?

Comment: The same units as the features that generated the convex hull.. what did you create it from?

Comment: NAD 83. This makes me think I need to recheck the area of the feature to make I didn't do something weird. I figured that's what the units were, it's just that the comparison between one and the other made no sense.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the difference between area($geometry) and $area. Once I used the former, I get numbers that make sense.